# Where is the Solver add-in in Microsoft Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, solver

I am looking for Solver in Microsoft Excel 2007 but cannot find it. How can I find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to [load it first](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/load-the-solver-add-in-HP010021570.aspx). Note that you might have to keep your Office installation CD ready.

> - Click the *Microsoft Office* Button [image: Microsoft Office Button], and then click *Excel Options*.
>
>   [image: Microsoft Office Menu]
> - Click *Add-Ins*, and then in the *Manage* box, select *Excel Add-ins*.
> - Click *Go*.
> - In the *Add-Ins available* box, select the *Solver Add-in* check box,
>     and then click *OK*.
> - If *Solver Add-in* is not listed in the *Add-Ins available* box,
>     click *Browse* to locate the add-in.
> - If you get prompted that the *Solver Add-in* is not currently
>     installed on your computer, click *Yes* to install it.
> - After you load the *Solver Add-in*, the *Solver* command is available in
>     the *Analysis* group on the *Data* tab.

Comment: Thanks! But when clicking the Microsoft Office Button , there is no Excel Options. Added: I found it.

Answer (score 1):

Following this [kb article for excel 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/load-the-solver-add-in-HP010021570.aspx) shows that you need to install the add-in:

> to use the Solver Add-in, however, you first need to load it in Excel.
>
> 1. Click the Microsoft Office Button , and then click Excel Options.
> 2. Click Add-Ins, and then in the Manage box, select Excel Add-ins.
> 3. Click Go.
> 4. In the Add-Ins available box, select the Solver Add-in check box,
>      and then click OK.
>
>    1. Tip    If Solver Add-in is not listed in the
>         Add-Ins available box, click Browse to locate the add-in.
>    2. If you get
>         prompted that the Solver Add-in is not currently installed on your
>         computer, click Yes to install it.
> 5. After you load the Solver Add-in,
>      the Solver command is available in the Analysis group on the Data tab.